# Dataframe to tidy format in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I've this dataframe

```
x <- data.frame("date" = c("03-01-2005","04-01-2005","05-01-2005","06-01-2005"), 
                "pricemax.0" = c(50,20,25,56), 
                "pricemax.200" = c(25,67,89,30),
                "pricemax.1000" = c(45,60,40,30),
                "pricemax.1400" = c(60,57,32,44),
                "pricemin.0" = c(22,15,23,43),
                "pricemin.200" = c(21,40,59,21),
                "pricemin.1000" = c(32,12,20,24),
                "pricemin.1400" = c(30,20,14,20))
```

The numbers after the dot represents hours, e.g `pricemax.200` would be 02:00. I need to gather the date and time information in one column of class `POSIXct` with the other two columns being `pricemax` and `pricemin`.

So, what I want is something like this:

[image: Tidy dataframe]

And what I've done so far:

```
tidy_x <- x %>% 
      pivot_longer(
        cols = contains("pricemax"),
        names_to = c(NA,"hour"),
        names_sep = "\\.",
        values_to = "pricemax"
      ) %>% 
      pivot_longer(
        cols = contains("pricemin"),
        names_to = c(NA,"hour_2"),
        names_sep = "\\.",
        values_to = "pricemin"
      )
```

I'm not sure how I can combine the date and time columns and keep the variables `pricemin` and `pricemax` organized.

Comment: underscore or dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -date, 
               names_to = c('.value', 'time'), 
               names_sep = '\\.') %>%
  mutate(time = sprintf('%04s', time)) %>%
  unite(datetime, date, time, sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(datetime = lubridate::dmy_hm(datetime))

# A tibble: 16 x 3
#   datetime            pricemax pricemin
#   <dttm>                 <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 2005-01-03 00:00:00       50       22
# 2 2005-01-03 02:00:00       25       21
# 3 2005-01-03 10:00:00       45       32
# 4 2005-01-03 14:00:00       60       30
# 5 2005-01-04 00:00:00       20       15
# 6 2005-01-04 02:00:00       67       40
# 7 2005-01-04 10:00:00       60       12
# 8 2005-01-04 14:00:00       57       20
# 9 2005-01-05 00:00:00       25       23
#10 2005-01-05 02:00:00       89       59
#11 2005-01-05 10:00:00       40       20
#12 2005-01-05 14:00:00       32       14
#13 2005-01-06 00:00:00       56       43
#14 2005-01-06 02:00:00       30       21
#15 2005-01-06 10:00:00       30       24
#16 2005-01-06 14:00:00       44       20
```

Get the data in long format with max and min in different column and hour information in different column. We make hour information consistent (of 4 digits) using `sprintf` and combine them into one column and convert it into datetime value.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try `reshape` like below to make a long data frame

```
y <- transform(
  reshape(x, direction = "long", varying = -1),
  date = strptime(paste(date, time / 100), "%d-%m-%Y %H")
)[c("date", "pricemax", "pricemin")]

y <- `row.names<-`(y[order(y$date),],NULL)
```

which gives

```
> y
                  date pricemax pricemin
1  2005-01-03 00:00:00       50       22
2  2005-01-03 02:00:00       25       21
3  2005-01-03 10:00:00       45       32
4  2005-01-03 14:00:00       60       30
5  2005-01-04 00:00:00       20       15
6  2005-01-04 02:00:00       67       40
7  2005-01-04 10:00:00       60       12
8  2005-01-04 14:00:00       57       20
9  2005-01-05 00:00:00       25       23
10 2005-01-05 02:00:00       89       59
11 2005-01-05 10:00:00       40       20
12 2005-01-05 14:00:00       32       14
13 2005-01-06 00:00:00       56       43
14 2005-01-06 02:00:00       30       21
15 2005-01-06 10:00:00       30       24
16 2005-01-06 14:00:00       44       20
```

Comment: the hour is missing from the datetime

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` approach:

```
setDT(x)
DT <- melt.data.table(x, id.vars = "date")

DT[, c("var", "time") := tstrsplit(variable , ".", fixed=TRUE)
][, datetime := as.POSIXct(paste(date, as.integer(time) / 100), format = "%d-%m-%Y %H")
][, setdiff(names(DT), c("datetime", "var", "value")) := NULL]

DT <- dcast.data.table(DT, datetime ~ var, value.var = "value")
```

---

```
> DT
               datetime pricemax pricemin
 1: 2005-01-03 00:00:00       50       22
 2: 2005-01-03 02:00:00       25       21
 3: 2005-01-03 10:00:00       45       32
 4: 2005-01-03 14:00:00       60       30
 5: 2005-01-04 00:00:00       20       15
 6: 2005-01-04 02:00:00       67       40
 7: 2005-01-04 10:00:00       60       12
 8: 2005-01-04 14:00:00       57       20
 9: 2005-01-05 00:00:00       25       23
10: 2005-01-05 02:00:00       89       59
11: 2005-01-05 10:00:00       40       20
12: 2005-01-05 14:00:00       32       14
13: 2005-01-06 00:00:00       56       43
14: 2005-01-06 02:00:00       30       21
15: 2005-01-06 10:00:00       30       24
16: 2005-01-06 14:00:00       44       20
```